# Why can't I use a variable of type float when "reducing" an array?

Tags: swift, floating-point, int, reduce

I have the following variable:

```
var calorieTotal: Float {
    return calorieNumberArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to add the numbers of an array I have together. First, I had the variable set to type `int`, but now I need it as a `float` value. When I try to do this, an error comes up: "'UInt8' is not a subtype of 'float'". How can I fix this? Please provide the code for the new/changed variable, as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that `calorieNumberArray` is an array of `Int` - in such case, just pass a float as initial value, and explicitly convert to `Float` the 2nd parameter passed to the closure:

```
var calorieTotal: Float {
    return calorieNumberArray.reduce(0 as Float) { $0 + Float($1) }
}
```

`$0` doesn't need conversion because it's already a float

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the error. And yes, the calorieNumberArray is an array of Int.